# azure web appでrequirements.txtに書かれたパッケージがインストールされない

Tags: python, azure

azureのapp serviceにて、Flaskをテンプレートとしたアプリ開発を行っているのですが、gitでcloneした際に一緒に落ちてきたrequirements.txtに使用したいモジュール名を記述した後にデプロイしたのですが、どうやらうまくいかず、インストールしてくれないようです。
こちらではrequestsを使用しようとしたのですが、上記の通り、うまくいかないために使用できませんでした。

[Azure App Service Web Apps による Python の構成](https://azure.microsoft.com/ja-jp/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-configure/)には

> requirements.txt 内のリストにあるパッケージが、pip を使用して仮想環境に自動的にインストールされます。これはデプロイメントごとに発生しますが、パッケージが既にインストールされている場合は、インストールがスキップされます。

とあるため、gitのpushのみで自動的にpypiからインストールされるのであろうと解釈しています。

どなたか解決策を回答していただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

どうやら、.skipPythonDeploymentというファイルがあるとPython固有のすべてのデプロイメント手順をスキップするようです。
今回は.skipPythonDeploymentを削除することで解決できました。

全て[こちら](https://azure.microsoft.com/ja-jp/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-configure/)に書いてありました。
解決済みです。